# Backpropogation neural network - error not converging

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation, neural-network

I am using backpropogation algorithm for my model. It works perfectly fine a simple xor case and when I tested it for a smaller subset of my actual data.

There are 3 inputs in total and a single output(0,1,2) 
I have split the data set into training set (80% amounting to approx 5.5k) and the rest 20% as validation data.

I use trainingRate and momentum for calculating the delta weights.

I have normalized the input as below

> > > from sklearn import preprocessing
> > >       min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
> > >       X_train_minmax = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(input_array)

I use 1 hidden layer with sigmoid and linear activation functions for input-hidden and hidden-output respectively.

I train with trainingRate = 0.0005, momentum = 0.6, Epochs = 100,000. Any higher trainingRate shoots up the error to Nan. momentum values between 0.5 and 0.9 works fine and any other value makes the error Nan.

I tried various number of nodes in the hidden layer such as 3,6,9,10 and the error converged to 4140.327574 in each case. I am not sure how to reduce this. Changing the activation functions doesn't help. I even tried adding another hidden layer with gaussian activation function but I cannot reduce the error whatsoever.

Is it because of the outliers? Do i need to clean those values from the training data?

Any suggestion would be of great help be it the activation function, hidden layers, etc. I had been trying to get this working for quite some time and I am sort of stuck now.

Comment: to test your hypothesis, try adding outliers to the simple cases and see how it reacts

Comment: The error did reduce to ~ 1.5k on some cleanup of outliers. However, the model isn't good yet because of the data, my applcation of the backpropogation algo or maybe both.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm having kind of a similar problem, still haven fixed it, but I can tell you a couple of things I have found. I think the net is overfitting, my error at some point goes down and then starts going up again, also the verification set... is this you case also?

Check if you are implementing well the "early stopping" algorithm, most of the times the problem is not the backpropagation, but the error analysis or the validation analysis.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I still haven't got the perfect model but  couple of changes helped reduce the error.

1. The output values I was using belonged to [0,1,2] while it should have been an array [1,0,0] or [0,1,0] or [0,0,1]
2. I used stochastic gradient descent to approach near global minima.

I shall update if I get any breakthrough.

Comment: As for overfitting, you might possibly have large number of nodes in the hidden layer. Reducing it might help. My issue is that it converges but the error cost is still significant to be even considered a decent hypothesis.